# About the definition of Radon measure on Kallenberg's book

Tags: measure-theory

I believe there are several definitions for Radon measure, which are equivalent under certain conditions. The one in the Wikipedia says that a measure $m$ on the $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets of Hausdorff space $X$ is called a **Radon measure** if both

- $m$ is **inner regular**, that is, for any open set $U$, $m(U)$ is the supremum of $m(K)$ over all compact subsets $K$ of $U$,
- and $m$ is **locally finite**, that is, every point of $X$ has a neighborhood $U$ for which $m(U)$ is finite.

Now I am concerned with the definition of Radon measure on O. Kallenberg's book 'Random Measures'. In the page 12 it says that a measure $\mu$ on $(\mathscr{G}, \mathscr{B})$(where $\mathscr{G}$ is a locally compact second countable Hausdorff space and $\mathscr{B}$ is the set of all relatively compact Borel sets) is **locally finite**(or **Radon**) if $\mu B < \infty$ for all $B \in \mathscr{B}$.

Are the two definitions equivalent in certain setting? Or are they completely different? I am trying to reference a paper that used the second definition for the phrase 'Radon measure'. And I wonder if I can assume that the 'Radon measure' has inner regularity, for example.

Comment: Rudin (RCA) proves that any positive Borel measure on a locally compact Hausdorff space which is finite in compact sets is inner regular. So, in the kind of spaces Kallenberg is considering the two definitions are equivalent.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you for commenting. I think you are mentioning Theorem 2.18. But it needs extra condition that every open sets are $\sigma$-compact. Is it naturally satisfied in locally compact second countable Hausdorff space?

Comment: Yes, that is true. Combine local compactness with the fact that any union of open sets is the union of a countable subfamily (in view of second coutability).